# The actual length is not expected when reading binary data by using nodejs http get from remote

Tags: node.js, sockets, http

I am new to Nodejs, I started to download some video files from public website by using http in Nodejs.
Below is a piece of my code. I met an issue, sometime I started too many connectoins to the target (too many callbacks start to download files), which caused the expected file length is different from the content-length. But the code didn't throw any error.

The connections seemed succeed, the files started to download, but after a very short period the 'end' event was triggered. The integrated file was not completely downloaded obviously. If the two length was mismatch, the file was broken. Exmaple output is:

> "done,size:17933430, expected:23333430".

Most of the time, when I started fewer callback( 4 callbacks at the same time), the file length matched to the content-length in Http header. I could get the integrated files.

I know that the target website has net connect limit. I think the nodejs http code should throw some kind of error, like socket reset or close. but now I didn't see the code throw error.
How can I capture the error? I guess the error is on socket level, are there any sample codes of Nodejs demostrating how to listen error event on socket underlying http?

I googled, but I can't find blogs or topics. Maybe the keyword is not percise.

```
    var http=require("http");
    var fs=require("fs");


[..file..list..].forEach(..


    ...
    var len = 0;
    var ws = fs.createWriteStream("/mydata/d.mp4");
    ...
    http.get("http://example.com/a.mp4", function (res) {
            var contlen = res.headers['content-length'];
            res.on("data", function (chk) {
              len += chk.length;
            });


            res.on("end",function(){
                console.log("done,size:"+len+", expected:"+contlen);

            });

            res.pipe(ws);

          }).on("error", function (error) {
            console.log( error);
          });
```

Comment: Start by declaring `len` (`var len = 0`) inside the callback.

Comment: ohhh.... Sorry, I lost the piece of code, I update my snip code in my question above. I already defined the variable len in my code.